# VBS Add numbers for each loop

Tags: variables, loops, vbscript

For my VBS script, for each loop, I want it to add the number of which loop it's on. Like if it's a site and has an ID, then if it's on loop 1 adds 1 to the ID. I already declared "site" for my script.

What do I do? Do you need to see some of the script?

Comment: can please you show us how far you have reached ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of collection you're working with, but you could do something simple like this

```
Set objFilesystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objInputFolder = objFileSystem.GetFolder("c:\temp")

i = 1
For Each objInputFile In objInputFolder.Files
   WScript.Echo SITE + i
   i = i + 1
Next
```